# Linq join with more than one condition?

Tags: linq

In linq i am trying to do like this

```
select * from tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1.column1= tbl2.column1 and tbl1.column2 = tbl2.column2
```

how can i write the above query in Linq.... i tried like this but giving error

```
  var sasi = from table1 in dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
             join table2 in dssap.AsEnumerable() 
             on new { 
                table1.Field<string >["SAPQuotationNo"],
                table1.Field<string >["Invoiceno"]} 
             equals new {  
                table2.Field<string>["SAPQuotationNo"],
                table2.Field <string>["Invoiceno"]
             }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use anonymous types
- give the properties names
- select something
- use `DataRow.Field` as method with round brackets

---

```
var sasi = from table1 in dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
           join table2 in dssap.AsEnumerable() 
           on new 
           { 
               SAPQuotationNo = table1.Field<string>("SAPQuotationN"),
               Invoiceno = table1.Field<string>("Invoiceno")
           } equals new 
           {
               SAPQuotationNo = table2.Field<string>("SAPQuotationNo"),
               Invoiceno = table2.Field<string>("Invoiceno") 
           }
           select table1;
```

Comment: tahnks for response, i will check and intimate u

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
from A in context.A
join B in context.B on new { id = B.ID,//..., type = A.ID,//...}
```

This is the hint, you can explore.